# Таблица выходит за границы ячейки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

На странице в bootstrap ячейку помещена таблица, в таблице достаточное количество столбцов, и на экранах ноутбуков эта таблица выходит за границы отведенной для нее ячейки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код страницы в этом месте:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row tablica">
        <table class="table table-striped tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    .....
                    <th>класс</th>
                    <th>расположение</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                ...
                <tr>
                    <td>текст</td>
                    <td>текст</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>текст</td>
                    <td>текст</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы таблица полностью поместилась в выделенный ей блок, а текст в широких столбцах скрылся за границами столбцов, но при hover на ячейку таблицы "ездил" "туда-назад"?

Comment: Код таблицы добавьте... Так мы не сможем понять в чем дело

Comment: @KryTer_NexT, добавил

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы пишете, что в таблице достаточное кол-во строк, может она банально не помещается в отведенное ей место?
Если так, используйте .table-responsive

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="row tablica table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped tablesorter">
      ...
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: при table-responsive таблица влезла в отведенный ей блок, но при этом под полосой прокрутки спряталась хорошая часть данных таблицы. Я хотел что бы в таблице сами ячейки уменьшились, а сам текст плавал по ячейке при hover-e